# How to know if Docker ENTRYPOINT completed execution

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I run a batch file when my container starts as part of the ENTRYPOINT directive in the dockerfile on Windows 10. Is there a way that host can know that the container has finished processing the batch file which is automatable through batch or powershell script on the host?

Thanks,

Comment: You could bind mount a host directory into the container and then create a flag file in that directory when processing is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Definitionally, when the `ENTRYPOINT` completes, the container exits.  If you run the container in the foreground (without the `docker run -d` option) or if you explicitly [`docker wait`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/wait/) for the container to finish, you can block the calling process on the container exiting.